# Structuremap can't find item when WhatDoIHave() reports it?

Tags: structuremap

I have a weird situation where StructureMap 2.6.4.1 is reporting a type as not being registered when it clearly is.

In a web api controller I have

```
    public RedirectToRouteResult GetSlideSet(int id) {
        var whatdoIHave = ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave();
        var dbctx = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyProject.Models.MyDbContext>();
        return RedirectToRoute(WebApiConfig.DefaultRouteName, new {controller="SlideSet", id});
    }
```

`WhatDoIHave` reports:

```
===========================================================================================================
...snip...

MyDbContext(MyProject.Models.MyDbContext)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Scoped as:  HttpContext

...snip...
```

This is the only reference to `MyDbContext` in WhatDoIHave

Yet I get an error when calling `GetInstance`:

```
StructureMap.StructureMapException occurred
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MyProject.Models.MyDbContext, MyProject, Version=2.4.5.25029, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
  Source=StructureMap
  ErrorCode=202
  StackTrace:
       at StructureMap.BuildSession.<.ctor>b__0(Type t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\BuildSession.cs:line 33
  InnerException:
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong or how even to troubleshoot this?

**Edit**: To Clarify, `MyDbContext` absolutely has a parameterless constructor but it also has a non-parameterless one (not that it should matter). I even created a unit test in my test project:

```
    [Fact]            
    public void get() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Configure(c => c.Configure(r => r.For<MyDbContext>().HttpContextScoped()) ));
        ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyDbContext>().ShouldNotBeNull();
    }
```

Which passes just fine. Oddly enough it was failing for a while in the same manner but then started succeeding while I was trying to narrow down the issue and I couldn't recreate the error. Does structuremap do some sort of system-wide caching?

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one implementation registered for that type?

Comment: @PhilSandler This is the only reference to MyDbContext in the `whatDoIHave` string. Also, in my experience, if I had more than one registration of `MyDbContext` it would show up right there.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used SM, so this may not be helpful, but is it tied to an interface, where you're trying to resolve the concrete type?

Comment: Nope, no interface, just a concrete instance registered with `For<MyDbContext>().HttpContextScoped();`. Pretty sure that an interface would have a separate entry in whatDoIHave

Comment: Hmm, does MyDbContext have a parameterless constructor?  I'm not sure if the lack of one gives this same error, or a more specific one.

Comment: It does have a parameterless constructor, yes.

Comment: Which Web.API dependency resolver implementation are you using? Also which Structuremap version are you using?

Comment: @nemesv 2.6.4.1 and your comment just made me recheck my unit test and I think I got it. Apparently structuremap was choking on multiple constructors and I my unit test assembly kept being cached somehow so my test runner kept running code that was not the most recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do after all with the fact that MyDbContext had multiple constructors.

```
MyDbContext() : base() { }
MyDbContext(connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }
```

Removing the second one fixed the issue in the unit test. This was confounded however by my unit test runner having issues and not being able to run the latest version of the code. I've got that sorted out and can now solve the issue with

```
For<MyDbContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use(() => new MyDbContext())
```